# Why do I keep getting a message that I am now offline even though I am wired to the router?

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a wired connection to a router.

I have never had any connectivity issues in the past, but now about every 10 minutes I get a message that says I am Offline even though I am not.

Comment: When it says you're 'offline', can you still ping an outside network such as running `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: In your router settings you might have "disconnect when inactive" set?